# Material-ui V3 is not loading first tab for after fetch data (or page load)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I used Material UI version 3 [scrollable-tab](https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/tabs/#scrollable-tabs), after fetch data to load tabs and tab container, but the first tab is not automatically load it on page load, require to click it to see information.

I've been google around, try to set this `initialSelectedIndex` still not working, I saw [a issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8728) from there Github, but does not have further information.
Here's [my reproduction code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-meadow-oxi88?fontsize=14)

Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the repos when the request made in componentDidMount is resolved:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const results = fetch("https://api.github.com/users")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        //fetch the repos
        this.handleReferences(data[this.state.value].repos_url);
        this.setState({ results: data });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Works great!! Thank you for the help!